# Spring RESTful websevices secured with Jasig CAS

Tags: spring, spring-security, cas, jasig

I have an existing Spring MVC/RESTful web application. Right now all of my REST endpoints secured with OAuth2.

Now, I need to reimplement security of my REST endpoints from OAuth2 to Jasig CAS.
I have already created my own CAS server and looking for an example how to secure Spring REST endpoints with CAS. Unfortunately I can't find any examples right now.

Could you please show me an example how to use Spring Security with CAS client in order to secure my Spring RESTful webservices.